# nullPointerException, guess when using getClass().getName()

Tags: java, classname

Reposting a question with more detail. The problem is a nullPointerException which occurs at clusterer.next(). Below is a simplified version of the program and am hoping you can notice where the issue is.

```
public class Clustering {
    private DistanceMeasure measure;  //Manhattan or Euclidean
    private ClusterMethod method;  //SingleLinkage or CompleteLinkage
    private Clusterer clusterer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Clustering().start();
    }
    Clustering() {
        measure = new Manhattan();
        method = new SingleLinkage(measure);
        clusterer = new Clusterer(method);
    }
    void start() {
        clusterer = setMethod();
        clusterer.next(); //would use the ClusterMethod to do some calculations; the nullException occurs here
    }
    Clusterer setMethod() {
        measure = new Euclidean();
        if (method.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("SingleLinkage")) {
             method = new CompleteLinkage(measure);
        }
        else method = new SingleLinkage(measure);
        return new Clusterer(method);
    }
}
public class Clusterer {
    private ClusterMethod method;

    Clusterer(ClusterMethod method) {
        this.method = method;
    }
    void next() {
        System.out.println(method.calculateDistance(0,1); //calculateDistance simply returns the 'distance' between 2 numbers.
    }
}
```

The code above works perfectly if i don't use the setMethod();

Comment: Please add a stacktrace.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at finalPAD.Clusterer.getClusterStep(Clusterer.java:23)
 at finalPAD.Clustering.performClusterStep(Clustering.java:91)
 at finalPAD.Clustering.processEvents(Clustering.java:54)
 at finalPAD.Clustering.proceedClustering(Clustering.java:48)
 at finalPAD.Clustering.start(Clustering.java:42)
 at finalPAD.Clustering.main(Clustering.java:34) where getClusterStep() is next() in my example here

Comment: Post the correct code snippet: finalPAD.Clusterer.getClusterStep(Clusterer.java:23 is where the error occurs and it is not shown in your code snippet

Comment: Unless you want me to post 20 classes of code, bear with me. The getClusterStep(Clusterer.java:23) line in the stacktrace in my actual program corresponds to the 'System.out.println(method.calculateDistance(0,1);' in my example here. Like I said, program works perfectly if I don't call setMethod() so i believe my way of handling the object references is wrong somewhere.

Comment: What happens in Clustering.performClusterStep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24364554/nullpointerexception-guess-when-using-getclass-getname/24365055#comment37675944_24364554) about where the exception occurs is correct, then `method` is `null`. You should verify this by using a debugger to step to that piece of code and inspect the statement. Alternatively, add Sysouts for all involved variables.

If this is unexpected, say you're convinced that `method`is set by some other part of your code, add a breakpoint or output to that other part to verify that it's actually doing what you think it's doing, and in the correct order, too.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I'm an idiot :) I was basically checking somewhere

```
"SingleLinkage".equals("Single Linkage")
```

which of course is always false and the method was not assigned any ClusterMethod. The code here is fine; stuff was going wrong in another place.